# NUnit no tests discovered

Tags: c#, nunit, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to get NUnit working for the first time.

I've tried:

1. Changing the default processor architecture in to X64
2. Installing all the most recent, stable versions of NUnit, NUnit Console and NUnit3TestAdapter.
3. I tried using NS2TestAdapter but that didn't make any difference

Here's the output:

```
------ Discover test started ------
NUnit Adapter 3.7.0.0: Test discovery starting
Dependent Assembly nunit.framework of c:\users\paul\documents\visual studio 
2017\Projects\bankAccount\bankAccount\bin\Debug\bankAccount.dll not found. 
Can be ignored if not a NUnit project.
NUnit Adapter 3.7.0.0: Test discovery complete
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00.0540843) ==========
```

The class to be tested:

```
using System;


namespace bankAccount
{
public class Account
{
    private int balance;

    public Account(int initialBalance)
    {
        balance = initialBalance;
    }

    public void credit(int amount)
    {
        balance += amount;
    }

    public void debit(int amount)
    {
        balance -= amount;
    }

    public int getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }
}
}
```

Then the Test Class:

```
  using System;
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Text;
  using bankAccount;
  using NUnit.Framework;

  namespace accountTest
  {
      [TestFixture]
      public class AccountTest
      {
    //private Account account;

    [Test]
    public void initialBalance()
    {
        Account account = new Account(100);
        Assert.AreEqual(100, account.getBalance());
    }

    [Test]
    public void credit()
    {
        Account account = new Account(100);
        account.credit(20);
        Assert.AreEqual(130, account.getBalance());
    }

    [Test]
    public void debitOk()
    {
        Account account = new Account(100);
        account.debit(20);
        Assert.AreEqual(80, account.getBalance());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Test runner and DLL framework/platform need to match. Have you tried the .NET Core test runner? https://github.com/nunit/dotnet-test-nunit

Comment: Thanks. I'm targeting 'Windows 10 Creators Update' which I found in the properties of my project. I'm using NUnit 3.7.x. I haven't tried the .NET Core test runner because I think that's for .NET Core projects, which mine isn't. What test runner version would match a target of Windows 10?